# running SVN scripts of users with no password

Tags: svn, command-line, tortoisesvn

I'm running SVN functions such as log from the command line.

I'm using --username and --password attributes to authenticate the function.

Unfortunately, my users don't have passwords and I'm don't know what value to provide in the command line for the password.

the syntax is:

--password ARG

and I don't have any value.

please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`--password ""` ?

Comment: Works for Me.  I.e. you'll need to expand on "my users don't have passwords" and/or show the exact command and exact error.  Also what svn server and authentication configuration.
I just tried with svnserve using a local passwd file.